# window.open does not work correctly in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

I have this form:

```
<form id="platba">
             <label class="c-input c-radio">
              <input id="radio1" name="radio" type="radio" value="https://www.paypal.com/uk/webapps/mpp/home">
              <span class="c-indicator"></span>
              <img src="img/payments/paypal.png" width="80" style="margin-top:-5px">&nbsp Paypal
            </label>
             <br />
             <br />
            <label class="c-input c-radio">
              <input id="radio2" name="radio" type="radio" value="http://www.mbank.cz/osobni/">
              <span class="c-indicator"></span>
              <img src="img/payments/mbank.png" width="80" style="margin-top:-5px">&nbsp mBank
            </label>
             <br />
             <br />
            <label class="c-input c-radio">
              <input id="radio2" name="radio" type="radio" value="http://example.com/platebnikarta">
              <span class="c-indicator"></span>
              <img src="img/payments/visa_mastercard.png" width="80" style="margin-top:-5px">&nbsp Platební karta
            </label>
            <hr>            

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Pokračovat v placení</button>
</form>
```

And at the end of the file i have javascript which open new window based on radio button selection:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#platba").submit(function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        var loc = $('input[name="radio"]:checked').val();
        window.open(loc,'_blank');
        //self.close ();
      });

    });
```

It is working fine in Google Chrome and IE, but in firefox it just add the value of radio button into the adressbar.
Example:

```
http://something/something/something/something.php?radio=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.paypal.com%2Fuk%2Fwebapps%2Fmpp%2Fhome
```

Comment: Not sure if this causes your problems, but the first thing I noticed is that you have two radio's with the same `id="radio2"`! (the second one and the third one). The third one should be `id="radio3"`

Comment: Perhaps the windows is blocked considered as a popup? try removing _blank, it should open as a new tab.

Comment: Thank you, i changed the id, but the problem still persist.

Comment: Removing "_blank" did not solved the problem.

Comment: afaik. every window.open that doesn't trigger withing like 40ms after a physical click-event (nothing simulated) is considered being a popup. **use a modal box**

Comment: I tried to run firefox in safe mode with addons disabled, did not helped.

Comment: FF doesn't use global event model, see @LaurensSwart answer below. That's said, if you just had opened your console to debug your code, you wouldn't have to post any question here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `event` in `event.preventDefault` is undefined. You have to define it in the function that you call it in:

```
$("#platba").submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Here is your corrected code that also works in Firefox (tested it myself on jsfiddle): https://jsfiddle.net/duzwo5bk/7/

Here is the code. **Note: it doesn't work here because you cannot do popups from these snippets on StackOverflow**

I also fixed the ID of your third radio :)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#platba").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var loc = $('input[name="radio"]:checked').val();
    window.open(loc, '_blank');
    //self.close ();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="platba">
<label class="c-input c-radio">
  <input id="radio1" name="radio" type="radio" value="https://www.paypal.com/uk/webapps/mpp/home">
  <span class="c-indicator"></span>
  <img src="img/payments/paypal.png" width="80" style="margin-top:-5px">&nbsp; Paypal
</label>
<br />
<br />
<label class="c-input c-radio">
  <input id="radio2" name="radio" type="radio" value="http://www.mbank.cz/osobni/">
  <span class="c-indicator"></span>
  <img src="img/payments/mbank.png" width="80" style="margin-top:-5px">&nbsp; mBank
</label>
<br />
<br />
<label class="c-input c-radio">
  <input id="radio3" name="radio" type="radio" value="http://example.com/platebnikarta">
  <span class="c-indicator"></span>
  <img src="img/payments/visa_mastercard.png" width="80" style="margin-top:-5px">&nbsp; Platební karta
</label>
<hr>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Pokračovat v placení</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you, it solved my problem.

Comment: You're most welcome! Pro tip: open the console in firefox (right click anywhere on your page, then click Inspect element, then select the console tab) and you would have seen your: `event is undefined` error :)